# Understanding the Quaternion rotation identity proof.

Tags: rotations, quaternions

I am doing a project about quaternions and their rotation. I am trying to get the proof of quaternion rotation identity by Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation to make sense. But I don't understand how they get from line $3$ and down. (Line $3$ which starts with: $$v(\cos^2(\frac{a}{2})-\sin^2(\frac{a}{2})\dots)$$

I also found a similar try on this website: https://erkaman.github.io/posts/quaternion_rotation.html, but don't understand the simplification there either.

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what parts confuse you? For example, “I don't understand where $-\sin^2\frac\alpha2$ appeared from in coefficient of $\vec v$”

Comment: @VasilyMitch
Fx i dont see how v*cos(alpha/2)^2 becomes v(cos(alpha/2)^2 - sin(alpha/2)^2)

noor how v(u . u) - 2*u(u . v)*sin(alpha/2)^2 becomes 2*u(u . v)*sin(alpha/2)

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\begin{aligned}
{\vec {v'}}&=
{\vec {v}}\cos ^{2}{\frac {\alpha }{2}}+({\vec {u}}{\vec {v}}-{\vec {v}}{\vec {u}})\sin {\frac {\alpha }{2}}\cos {\frac {\alpha }{2}}-{\vec {u}}{\vec {v}}{\vec {u}}\sin ^{2}{\frac {\alpha }{2}}\\[6pt]
&=\color{blue}{{\vec {v}}\cos ^{2}{\frac {\alpha }{2}}}+2({\vec {u}}\times {\vec {v}})\sin {\frac {\alpha }{2}}\cos {\frac {\alpha }{2}}-(\color{blue}{{\vec {v}}({\vec {u}}\cdot {\vec {u}})}-\color{red}{2{\vec {u}}({\vec {u}}\cdot {\vec {v}})})\color{purple}{\sin ^{2}{\frac {\alpha }{2}}}\\[6pt]
&=\color{blue}{{\vec {v}}(\cos ^{2}{\frac {\alpha }{2}}-\sin ^{2}{\frac {\alpha }{2}})}+({\vec {u}}\times {\vec {v}})(2\sin {\frac {\alpha }{2}}\cos {\frac {\alpha }{2}})+\color{red}{{\vec {u}}({\vec {u}}\cdot {\vec {v}})(2\sin ^{2}{\frac {\alpha }{2}})}\\[6pt]
&={\vec {v}}\cos \alpha +({\vec {u}}\times {\vec {v}})\sin \alpha +{\vec {u}}({\vec {u}}\cdot {\vec {v}})(1-\cos \alpha )\\[6pt]&=({\vec {v}}-{\vec {u}}({\vec {u}}\cdot {\vec {v}}))\cos \alpha +({\vec {u}}\times {\vec {v}})\sin \alpha +{\vec {u}}({\vec {u}}\cdot {\vec {v}})\\[6pt]&={\vec {v}}_{\bot }\cos \alpha +({\vec {u}}\times {\vec {v}})\sin \alpha +{\vec {v}}_{\|}
\end{aligned}
$$

Since $\vec u$ is a unit vector, $\vec u\cdot\vec u=1$. Is it clear now?

Comment: Ok it makes more sense now yes, but why do you say that 1=sin^2(alpha/2) (in the part highligted with blue)? 
Since the grundrelation is cos(x)^2+sin(x)^2=1?
Sorry for all the questions, but i really appreciate it!

Comment: The purple coefficient $\sin^2\alpha/2$ belongs to both blue and red terms.

Comment: Argh! makes sense! thank you so much! have a great evening